# 'requests' has no attribute 'response

Tags: python, api

I am trying to use the VirusTotal API for python to check for urls. The code works fine however, the output is a everything in one line so its hard to read. I tried to split the lines but it does not split into seperate lines. How do I solve it

```
import requests



url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/url/report'

params = {'apikey': '', 'resource':''}

response = requests.get(url, params=params)

requests.split('\n')

print(response.json())


input()
```

when I run this way I get an error as AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'response'.

Can someone help me in resolving this issue please.

Thanks!

Comment: Should not you be using `response.split('\n')` ?

Comment: Try without split. That's a Response object, not a string.

Comment: response('\n') It is not working

Comment: The error you pasted is very misleading. Is this the exact code you ran ? Paste the exact `traceback` from the output you get

Comment: yes. Its available on https://developers.virustotal.com/reference#scanning-urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks For your help! But when I researched you need to have a separate helper for this. It is readily available in

https://equalsequals.io/2018/02/22/building-a-simple-virustotal-client-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

`response.text` is the response string. Also use `json.loads()` depending to the url response.

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/url/report'

params = {'apikey': '', 'resource':''}

response = requests.get(url, params=params)

print(json.dumps(response.text))
```

Comment: response.json() is same as json.loads(response.text). @Jacky simply pprint(response.json) to see how the response looks and then split if needed

Comment: @ankeshpandey if it is loaded as json then he cannot split it for sure. But the response object is not a valid string. He should parse the `response.text`

Comment: I get an error saying  "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list" when using json.loads(response)

Comment: @Jacky That's why I told you depending on what your request returns. Try `json.dumps()`

Comment: @ ankesh pandey when I simply put print (response.json) I get as response 200 but no output. If the request is succeeded how do I get the results

Comment: @ Kostas Charitidis even if I replaced with dumps it is not working

Comment: @Jacky I'm trying to reproduce but it seems that the url is not working.

Comment: I guess you need an api key from VirusTotal & then add a url for 'resource'

Comment: @Jacky yeap most probably. So you get data or not? Try to parser to json the `response.text` while split will make it a list of elemetns.

Comment: is json.loads(response.text.split('\n')) not working for you?   what do you see when you do pprint(response.json()) ? response.text, response.content, response.json() should all give you output while response.status_code will give you 200

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import requests



url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/url/report'

params = {'apikey': '', 'resource':''}

response = requests.get(url, params=params)
data = response.json()


print(data)
```